# Filter with multiple derived classes with Code-first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Lets say I have a `User` with 2 derived entities `Student`, `Teacher`. I used the TPH method, so I actually have no property at all in my classes to tell me who is a teacher or not.

I have 2 booleans that should allow me to load either student or teacher such as this:

```
//IQueryable<User>
var query = userRepository.GetUsers();

//Type filtering
if (searchModel.IsStudent)
{
    query = query.OfType<Student>();
}
if (searchModel.IsTeacher)
{
    query = query.OfType<Teacher>();
}
```

When this tries to evaluate, I get this error when both are true:

`DbIsOfExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument.`

I already looked at some answers here on SO but they are geared towards 1 type of filtering.

I would then like to do something like this (rough coding):

```
if(query.ToList().FirstOrDefault() is Student)
{
     print "student";
}
```

The mapping:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .Map<Teacher>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Teach"))
                    .Map<Student>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Stu"))
                    .Map<Staff>(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Staff"));
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your classes? Are you using code first? Any mapping code you can share?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I added the query type

Comment: If you want to "load *either* student *or* teacher", why do you have two booleans which both can be true? Catch that case as infeasible and you are done. Even if you didn't have that exception the result would be always empty anyway because in your model a user can't be a `Student` and a `Teacher` at the same time. If you want to be able to filter both at the same time, you would need a logical OR and not chain the queries (which represents a logical AND).

Comment: @Slauma I would like to combine them, so both can be true, could you give a code snippet example of how this would look?

Comment: `if (searchModel.IsStudent && !searchModel.IsTeacher) query = query.OfType<Student>(); else if (searchModel.IsTeacher && !searchModel.IsStudent) query = query.OfType<Teacher>();` BrokenGlass already had answered this but deleted his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one. It works at least for EF 5.

```
IQueryable<User> Filter(this IQueryable<User> query, 
    bool includeTeacher, bool includeStudent)
{

  return query.Where(x => includeTeacher && x is Teacher
                || includeStudent && x is Student);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but it will work for what you need:

```
if (searchModel.IsStudent && searchModel.IsTeacher) 
{
    var result = context.Users.OfType<Teacher>()
                        .Cast<User>()
                        .Union(context.Users.OfType<Student>());
}
```

And It will run on one query!! :)